# Define a common trait for types with different numbers of type parameters

Tags: scala, generics

Suppose I have two traits:

```
trait Generic1[T] {
  def mapR[U](f: Result[T] => Result[U]): Generic1[U]
}

trait Generic2[A, T] {
  // pretty much the same as Generic1, but with the extra `A` type param
  def mapR[U](f: Result[T] => Result[U]): Generic2[A, U]
}
```

Is there a way that I can define a single trait that defines some common functionality based on the `mapR` method?

```
// for example
trait MapR[T, ???] {
  def mapR[U](f: Result[T] => Result[U]): ???[U]

  def map[U](f: T => U): ???[U] = mapR(_ map f)
  def flatMap[U](f: T => Result[U]): ???[U] = mapR(_ flatMap f)
  def withFilter(f: T => Boolean): ???[T] = mapR(_ withFilter f)
}
```

How would the `???` be defined in the `MapR` trait above so that I could instead define

```
trait Generic1[T] extends MapR[T, ???]
trait Generic2[A, T] extends MapR[T, ???]
```

---

**extra issues**

@m-z's answer handles the question asked above, but I run into some further troubles when the GenericN traits have type variance:

```
trait Generic1[+T] extends MapR[T] {
  type R[X] = Generic1[X]
  ...
}
trait Generic2[-A, +T] extends MapR[T] {
  type R[X] = Generic2[A, X]
  ...
}
```

I get errors like "contravariant type A occurs in invariant position in type [X]Generic2[A, X] of type R"

I tried redefining R to be covariant, but it still doesn't touch the `A` type and I get similar errors.

Can the approach in the answer be adapted to handle the type variance described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `MapR` trait have a type member with a single type parameter than can alias the `Generic` traits on implementation. This would require each `Generic` trait to describe how it is parameterized.

```
trait Result[T]

trait MapR[T] {

  type R[U]

  def mapR[U](f: Result[T] => Result[U]): R[U]

}

trait Generic1[T] extends MapR[T] {
  type R[U] = Generic1[U]
}

trait Generic2[A, T] extends MapR[T] {
  type R[U] = Generic2[A, U]
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting because this answered my question as I asked it. But I had omitted (for brevity) the fact that my actual GenericN traits are covariant on `T` and contravariant on `A`. Following this approach, I haven't been able to get it to compile on my actual traits. I edited the question to add some more info on this, in the "extra issues" section.

Comment: @Dylan You can make `Result`, `MapR`, `Generic1`, `Generic2`, and `type R` all covariant over `T`.

Comment: That works in `Generic1`, but in `Generic2` when I write `type R[+U] = Generic2[A, U]` I still get "contravariant type A in invariant position in type..."

Answer (score 1):

You could probably achieve this by declaring the supertrait as higher-kinded. Something along these lines might be possible:

```
trait Result[T]

trait MapRSupport[SelfType[X], T] {
  def mapR[U](f: Result[T] => Result[U]): SelfType[U]
}

trait Generic1[T] extends MapRSupport[Generic1, T]{
  def mapR[U](f: Result[T] => Result[U]): Generic1[U] = ???
}

trait Generic2[A] extends MapRSupport[Generic2, A]{
  type T
  // pretty much the same as Generic1, but with the extra `A` type param
  def mapR[U](f: Result[T] => Result[U]): Generic2[A] { type T = U} = ???
}
```